# Import and export databases,phpmyadmin

Tags: export, import, phpmyadmin

How import and export databases in phpmyadmin?
I can find my databases on my house's pc, but I want to work with my database on school's pcs. So what i want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your database, click to export, select the format (if you use it only for database save it as sql) then select the folder where you want to save. Then when you have to open it you have to select the extension, and where to pick it.